# Updating a model based on view changes by the user?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QStandardItemModel` that gets displayed by a `QTableView`.

Here's a sample `QTableView`:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
| C    | D    |
+------+------+
```

The indices for each cell are as follows:

```
[0,0]: A
[0,1]: B 
[1,0]: C
[1,1]: D
```

I allow the user to reorder the columns in the `QTableView` like so:

```
+------+------+
| Col2 | Col1 |
+------+------+
| B    | A    |
| D    | C    |
+------+------+
```

The indices stay the same because the user has changed the *view* and not the *model*. But I want the model (and the indices) to get updated when the user reorders the columns in the view. How do I change the model so that I get the following?

```
[0,0]: B
[0,1]: A 
[1,0]: D
[1,1]: C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `model` is of type `QStandardItemModel*` and there really are only two columns then you should be able to simply do...

```
QStandardItem *root = model->invisibleRootItem();
for (int row = 0; row < root->rowCount(); ++row) {
  QStandardItem *left = root->child(row, 0);
  QStandardItem *right = root->child(row, 1);
  QMap<int, QVariant> data = model->itemData(left->index());
  model->setItemData(left->index(), model->itemData(right->index()));
  model->setItemData(right->index(), data);
}
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do that though -- seems to violate the model/view separation idea.

Comment: There are many more than just 2 columns. This question is a simpler version of one I couldn't get answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802081/copying-a-selection-in-a-qtableview-properly-model-index-issues

Comment: That's a **very** different question.

Comment: It's complicated, yes. But by having that extra set of indexes, I'd be able to base the selection off of the visual indexes instead of the model indexes and this have the selection ranges act as intended (left to right per row instead of top to bottom).